# Represent percentages in Echarts

Tags: reactjs, echarts

I m trying to represent percentages in barcharts (apache echarts).

my current approach for this is like this

```
series: [
       {
        type: 'bar',
        stack: 'total',
        barCategoryGap: 15,
        data: [
            {
                value: 0.05,
                itemStyle: {
                    color: 'red',
                },
            },
            {
                value: 0.25,
                itemStyle: {
                    color: 'gray',
                },
            },
            {
                value: 0.5,
                itemStyle: {
                    color: theme.colors.ups,
                },
            },
        ],
        showBackground: true,
        backgroundStyle: {
            color: 'black',
            borderRadius: 3,
        },
        itemStyle: {
            borderRadius: 3,
        },
    },
    {
        type: 'bar',
        stack: 'total',
        barCategoryGap: 15,
        data: [
            {
                value: 0.95,
                itemStyle: {
                    color: 'transparent',
                },
            },
            {
                value: 0.75,
                itemStyle: {
                    color: 'transparent',
                },
            },
            {
                value: 0.5,
                itemStyle: {
                    color: 'transparent',
                },
            },
        ],
        showBackground: true,
        backgroundStyle: {
            color: 'black',
            borderRadius: 6,
        },
        itemStyle: {
            borderRadius: 6,
        },
    },
],
```

this works as intended
[here is the preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIfXP.png)

but there should be an easy way for this... when i remove second stack(in my approach)... this doesnt work as intended.
[Look at this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/id1KK.png)

Is there an easy way for this?

I want to represent percentages in the echarts barchart. if it is 50% the half of the bar should be filled, if its 25% quater of the bar should be filled.

Comment: Instead of using `backgroundStyle` to create this effect, you can directly set the `barWidth: '50%', ` property and use the color property to achieve the desired result.

Comment: just set the [min](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#yAxis.min) and [max](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#yAxis.max) property  of your `yAxis` to 0 and 1.

Comment: @MatthiasMertens it worked... but I want the same for pie chart, but there are no axis in it.

Comment: I dont understand what you want to do. Pie charts represent percentages naturally.